# On the careers site, sometimes the relative date (for a job posting, for example) is poorly worded

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, languages

On one job posting, for instance, it says:

> *posted on 2 weeks ago*

If you're using relative dating, the "*on*" should probably be omitted.

Comment: I don't know why we need relative dates anywhere, to be honest. I can perform date arithmetic and figure out that 2012-09-06 was two weeks ago, if I want to think about it that way. Most of the time, I don't. That said, this grammar check should be pretty simple...

Comment: I agree that in general relative dating is relatively useless (ha).  That said, on job postings is one place where I can see its utility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is handled and will go out with the next push later today.